# How do I build multiple versions of the same iOS application for OEMs

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an existing iOS application that I need to be able to build and release multiple versions of for different clients.

This application interfaces with hardware that is available from a handful of different companies, the hardware is identical but each company sells the hardware under a different name

This is a free app, the goal is not to spam the appstore with multiple versions of the same app, the goal is to allow companies that sell rebranded hardware to have a mobile app that uses the brand name that they use for the hardware.

What I need to be able to do:

- Build multiple versions of the same application that can be submitted to the Appstore, each version would be submitted under a different companies apple account.  I would assume that means multiple projects so that each project can use a company specific provisioning profile
- Each version has some different images (Icon, startup image, maybe a few others)
- Each version has some different strings (Company name, Product Name, maybe a few others)

With Android I just create a library project and I can override strings and images with a trivial amount of effort.

With iOS I haven't found an obvious answer.

I looked into adding a new target to my existing project but I don't think that will work:
- I can't figure out how to replace images beyond the icon and starting screen
- I can't figure out how to replace strings
- Would I be able to use different provisioning profiles for the different apps that compile with the same project?  I know the target settings allow different provisioning profiles, but doesn't the project settings have its own set of provisioning profiles?

Can I package the current application into a library that other projects can use and replace images/strings?  So each version would have its own xCode project but use the same code.

Maybe I need to work more with the idea of multiple targets...

I am using xCode 4.2, but I am prepared to move to a newer version if necessary

Comment: You can check this blog post here talking about how to do it all http://khaledannajar.blogspot.com/2017/02/how-to-use-targets-to-launch-multiple.html

Comment: you can find the answer if you start look around implementing `.xcconfig` files for your targets.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create multiple targets that use different Info.plist files.  The biggest difference will be different bundle identifiers.  You can also define different preprocessor macros that will control the conditional compilation of various chunks of code.

Alternatively/additionally, you can put your build configuration settings (including the changing location of the Info.plist file) into *.xcconfig files and reference those in your project, info, configurations area.  Then, you can build a different version of your app by simply by changing your scheme.  Putting build configration settings into files is a huge win for configuration control too.

Here's a link to setting up *.xcconfig files: http://itcoding.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-xcconfig-abandoning-build-panel.html.  I've seen other articles like this as well -- but this one will get you started.

Good luck.

Comment: The multiple targets with different info.plist files is exactly what I needed.  The other part was having separate folders for images for each oem, and in xCode make sure that the images are set to only be included with the proper target

Answer (score 4):

I did this differently at my last company, where we generated around 8 apps from one primary source repository.

We created one project that required one external class, call it Config. That class vended the unique info that makes each app unique.

Then to spin one app you create your App project, include the common "library", provide the Config.m file (Config.h is common), add the unique images etc.

Comment: i did the same with my first project... today is a pain in the ass... :)

Comment: you need to manage multiple project and keep them always updated. I hope that you did it with a version control tool.

Comment: @TommasoResti  I did. If you find a better way to do it post it here, as an alternate answer. It's possible you could have one project with multiple targets in it.

Comment: i did it with multiple targets... like @Erik wrote

Comment: @TommasoResti then why clog up my un-accepted answer? Its still one option you can take? Its a 6 o one, half dozen of another. You like the other approach, I'm glad for you!

Comment: I just wanted to warn new developers that your approach (which I used too years ago) it's difficult to manage.

Comment: maybe do i downvoted your answer? i don't think... what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This was very helpful for me. It is essentially the multi-target approach but you customize it for a company and you upload to their account.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/304/ See from the 17 minute mark.

To summarize, you partner with the company you are developing for, from their Apple Connect account, they assign you as the developer and marketing role for the specific apps you are developing for them. You upload your builds to their account. They get ultimate decision of when they will release it and who will test it with TestFlight.