# Xcode :Multiple Build Configuration of same project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an Xcode project and i want to change AppName,App Icon some images and others string, based on selected build at run time.

I want build configuration in 4 different names. Please suggest me, is it possible to do all build configuration in same project or create different project for different build.

Thanks!

Comment: may be this will help:[http://stackoverflow.com/a/11473464/5575752](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11473464/5575752)

Comment: @RonakChaniyara , thanks for sharing but, where i will do appname change, image change, build number and other configs.

Answer (score 1):

Friend you need to create multiple targets of your application. Follow follwing links,

http://www.appcoda.com/using-xcode-targets/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11473464/4294543

http://www.folio3.com/blog/using-multiple-targets-in-xcode/

[image]

**For changing app name**

You can change it by multiple ways,

> Go to Project navigator > Select target > Go to general > Display name

Or

> You can change it from Project navigator > Select target >  Build Settings > `Product Name`

**For Different xcassets & appIcon for each target**

> Add new file > Asset Catalog > Give Name & don't forget to select for which target you want to add from bottom

[image]

Comment: so appname i have to chnage each time i run the build

Comment: No, bro if you set for each target, its already different for each target.

Comment: each time u r changing appname and selecting image asset, can we have all things in project and based on build selction it should all get chnage automatically

Comment: You have to make changes for the target only once & when you `Set the active scheme` it will archive or make build for that target only.

Comment: so appname and appicon should be always change manually on run time for particular build